# Interpreting elm function declaration syntax

Tags: elm

I am not able grasp the following function declaration & definition syntax of elm language.

```
keyDown: (Int -> Msg) -> Attribute msg
keyDown event = 
  on "keydown" (Json.map event keyCode)
```

What does the first line means?
`keyDown: (Int -> Msg) -> Attribute msg`. Does it means, that the `keyDown` function takes, `Int` & `Msg` type params & returns of type `Attribute`?

What exactly happens in the function definition part?

How the parameters to the function are defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

`keyDown` function accepts another function as an argument and returns an attribute, which Elm's renderer uses to attach an event listener.

If you define a type

```
type Msg
    = KeyDown Int
```

The `KeyDown` acts as a constructor function for values of type `Msg`, so we can say that the implicit type of it is `KeyDown: Int -> Msg`, which is what you want when you want to retrieve a key code from a DOM Event.

#### Explanation

First of all, I must say that the proper implementation should look like this:

```
keyDown : (Int -> msg) -> Attribute msg
keyDown tagger =
    on "keydown" (Json.Decode.map tagger keyCode)
```

It is important to have `msg` type variable in the signature, so it's possible to use this event listener in different parts of the application, where `Html` emits different types of `msg`

To understand what is happening here, let's look closer at [Html.Events.on](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Events#on)

```
on : String -> Decoder msg -> Attribute msg
```

Every DOM event is represented as a JavaScript object with certain fields. To retrieve the data from JavaScript, Elm needs to pass it through a [Decoder](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#Decoder) to ensure type safety in runtime, just like with HTTP requests.

The decoder in `on` is expected to produce the same type of message, as the attribute itself.

By default, [keyCode](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Events#keyCode) decoder decodes an `Int` value, but what we want is to emit some message.

That's where [Json.Decode.map](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#map) helps us to get the `Int` and apply some `tagger` function, which produces a message.

#### Decoder

The entire `(Json.map event keyCode)` part is essentially a `Decoder msg`, which is applied to the event object to extract the key code and "tag" it with a message.

Comment: Hi, Thank for the reply. What is `tagger` here?

Comment: @explorer "tagger" is a general name for those functions, that retrieve data from decoders and convert them into messages.

Comment: My problem is with the syntax. Could you please explain me the below each part?
`keyDown tagger =
    on "keydown" (Json.Decode.map tagger keyCode)`. Not being able to interpret `keyDown tagger = `.
Like, Not being able to interpret `on "keydown" (Json.Decode.map tagger keyCode)`. If I could do that, then most of the things would suddenly make sense. From the documentation, I am able to understand that `on` function takes a `even name(string)` & `decoder`. But, I am not able to get, what `(Json.Decode.map tagger keyCode)` exactly means. Could you please explain?

Comment: For example, from `(Json.Decode.map tagger keyCode)`, what I am not able to understand is, which function is called, what is the input & what is the output?

Comment: Okay, now I see that `Json.Decode.map` is a function, `tagger` & `keyCode` are parameters to `map` function. But, I am still not able to understand that how & where each of these parameters are created.

Comment: @explorer `tagger` is the function you pass as an argument and `keyCode` is coming from [Html.Events.keyCode](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Events#keyCode), it is an alias for `Json.Decode.int`. You can think of it as `(Json.Decode.map (\int -> tagger int) Json.Decode.int)` where the output of `tagger int` will be the data you get from DOM Event(key code in this specific case)

Comment: Cool! I have got it. Thank you!

Comment: @explorer happy to help!